# How to avoid stretching of textures whiile extruding the mesh?

Tags: texturing, extrude

I am creating a beat/pumping effect animation but when i extrude the mesh with shape keys, the extruding edges are really sharp and also with stretching texture (Fig 2).Also from front view there are some irregularities (Fig 1). Is there any way to make the extrusion smooth without the irregularities and also to avoid the stretching.?

[image]

[image]

Comment: in edit mode, look at the options (top right of 3d view) and check "correct face attribute"... but this may work or not depending on what you are modifying.

Comment: sorry, i couldnt find the option there

Comment: it's in 2.9 version

Comment: ok, just noticed you are using 2.83. the option I mentioned is available in 2.9.

Comment: Ohh. Is there any other way to make it smooth?